# How to extract string from backtrace() ouput in C and store it in char*

Tags: c

I got the backtrace output as below

```
/home/jalv3/adv/adv2/local/libprog.so(func+0x2d) [0x8fe46911ac6d]
```

Now I want to extract only "libprog.so" and "0x8fe46911ac6d" and store it in a char *

Tried to use strtok and strchr as shown , but not getting the desired output

```
 char * str = "/home/jalv3/adv/adv2/local/libprog.so(func+0x2d) [0x8fe46911ac6d]";
    char * pp=strchr(str, '[');
    char line[256];
    char *subString;
    strcpy(line, str);
    subString = strtok(line,"/");
    subString=strtok(NULL,"(");
    printf("string 1= %s\n",pp);
    printf("string 2 = %s\n",subString);
```

The output is

```
string 1 = [0x8fe46911ac6d] 
string 2 = jalv3/adv/adv2/local/libprog.so
```

Comment: "Tried to use strtok and strchr , but not getting the desired output". Likely your code has some errors. But we can't tell you what you have done wrong unless you show us the code. Please provide a [mcve]. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have made no attempt to remove the parts of the two result string that you are not interested in. Why can you not continue to apply the same logic that you have already used on the two strings to remove those unwanted parts? That is, you seem to know what to do with `strtok` and `strchr` and have simply not completed the job.

Comment: @kaylum:what do you mean by doing the same thing,if I repeat I am getting different output, can you please specify how should I complete it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply continue parsing the string to get the result you want. For example, add the following code before the last `printf` to achieve the result you want.

```
/* subString = jalv3/adv/adv2/local/libprog.so at this point */

/* Reverse search to find the last '/' character */
subString = strrchr(subString, '/');

/* Jump past the '/' */
subString++

/* This will print: string 2 = libprog.so */
printf("string 2 = %s\n", subString);
```

I will leave the other string as an exercise for you.